# Left regular representation as a representable functor

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory, representation-theory, functors

[image]

Let $A$ be a category with one object $\star$. Then as far as I understand, the unique representable functor is $A(\star,-):A\to Set$. Isn't this representable functor genuinly unique, not just up to isomorphism? If not, what is an example of two distinct (but isomorphic) representable functors?

Also, is there an explicit description of left regular representation? How to obtain it?

Answer (score 1):

The set you get when applying $A(\ast,-)$ to $\ast$ is the underlying set of $\mathrm{End}(\ast)$. But there's no requirement that a functor creates that kind of set. For instance, if $B$ is any one-element set in $\mathsf{Set}$, then $B\times A(\ast,-)$ is not technically the same functor as $A(\ast,-)$, although there is a clear natural isomorphism $A(\ast,-)\cong B\times A(\ast,-)$ given by $x\mapsto (b,x)$.

If $M$ is a monoid, the left regular representation means the action of $M$ on itself given by the binary operation on the monoid. That is, the monoid operation $M\times M\to M$ is the action. The image of the functor $A(\ast,-)$ then would bet the set $\mathrm{End}(\ast)$ and each morphism $f:\ast\to\ast$ would turn into a function $\mathrm{End}(\ast)\to\mathrm{End}(\ast)$ given by $g\mapsto f\circ g$.

Comment: Note that it is not assumed that the one object category is a groupoid. Therefore "$\text{Aut}(\ast)$" should be replaced by "$\text{End}(\ast)$" in the first paragraph, and "bijection" should be replaced by "map" in the last paragraph.

Comment: @Nex Oops, corrected.

Comment: What do you mean by $End(\ast)$? Usually $End(G)$ denotes the endomorphism ring of an abelian group $G$, but $\star$ is not an abelian group, it's some object.

Comment: @user634426 In category theory, endomorphism means any morphism from an object to itself. So ${\rm End}(x)$ will be the set of all endomorphisms of an object $x$ (and with the composition operation, that makes it a monoid).

Comment: Is it obvious that any representable functor is naturally isomorphic to $A(\star,-)$?

Comment: @user634426 In order to be called representable, it must be naturally isomorphic to $A(x,-)$ for some object $x$ in the category. How many objects are in the category in question?

Comment: One. But regardless of how many elements the category has, my previous question now makes no sense to me. Any representable functor is by definition naturally isomorphic to $A(\star,-)$.